# Java Generic Type non-static method return Object instead of generic type T

Tags: java, class, generics, non-static

```
public class Module<T> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T module(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(this);
    }
        
}
```

This is the base class of my module and I want to initialize it to TestModule by calling the module method above.

```
TestingModule testingModule = new Module().module(TestingModule.class);
```

However, the return type of

> new Module().module(TestingModule.class)

is Object instead of TestingModule. Is there any idea that I can directly initialize it **without using any casting** or changing the method to **static**?

Comment: You're not using the class' generic type so either remove that (though I assume you want to use it elsewhere), change the method's generic type to something else (.e.g. `<U> U module(Class<U> clazz)`) or actually _use_ the class' type: remove the `<T>` from the method and create your module as `new Module<TestModule>`.

Comment: `TestingModule` vs `TestModule`. Maybe you mixed those up. The compiler surely doesn't infer the method-level `T` to `TestingModule`, which is why you're getting `Object`. But the fact that you're hiding the class-level type variable `T` with the method-level one is very dodgy.

Comment: @ernest_k Oh sorry, typo in my question. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems. The one most directly linked to the type mismatch error is here:

```
TestingModule testingModule = new Module().module(TestingModule.class);
```

`new Module()` is using `Module` without any type argument. When you use a raw type like this, you lose all generic information in the expression. You can fix it simply by adding a type argument:

```
TestingModule testingModule = new Module<String>().module(TestingModule.class);
```

In the above code, I've added `<String>` to the constructor call, which resolves the problem. But `String` is as strange a type argument as it can get in this case, which leads to the following side note.

The declaration `public <T> T module(Class<T> clazz)` adds a type variable `T` that hides the class-level type variable of the same name. If this method is not made generic by accident, please use a different name for this variable, **and use it**. Otherwise, this method doesn't need to be generic.